# Change Driver dialog for printer hangs

Tags: drivers, printing

I'm trying to change the default driver for a network attached printer. I click on the Change... button and the resulting dialog for choosing the driver goes grey then hangs, eventually I get the message '"Printers" is not responding'. I never get the chance to select the "Provide PPD file" option.

I installed the printer automagically, but it selected the wrong device type (FS-2000D instead of FS-2020D), and the test page doesn't work correctly.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Kyocera FS-2020D printer.

Have I missed something?

Comment: The picture becomes a little clearer! 

(1) The printer is set to PCL emulation by default. If I change this to KPDL (Kyocera's postscript implementation) and connect the printer directly via USB, hey presto, all works.

(2) In real life the printer is connected to a TP-Link printer server (PS310U) to share in my local network. No combination of printer emulation (PCL6 / KPDL) and printer driver appears to produce correct output - mostly postscript or PCL error messages

(3) The periodic printer settings dialog hang still occurs, as originally reported.

Answer (score 3):

This bug seems to have been reported here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1883370

There is a fix provided by Ikuya Awashiro
[https://launchpad.net/~ikuya-fruitsbasket/+archive/ubuntu/scp](https://launchpad.net/%7Eikuya-fruitsbasket/+archive/ubuntu/scp)

I tried his PPA and it seemed to have fixed the hang issue: Available drivers can be shown and chosen, no more useless hang.